# Where to increase max heap for Fuse ESB router?

Tags: java, jbossfuse, fuseesb, max-heap

About once per month, our router component hangs, halting traffic.  It logs a "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error.  I think it's consistently using about .5 GB of physical memory.

It looks like config files are placed in "C:\fmc-1.0.2.fuse-097\instances\esb-router-container\etc", but I found no place for jvm options.  Where is the prescribed place for adding "-Xmx512m", or whatever?

I'm not excited about upgrading the entire esb to the lastest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fabric:container-edit-jvm-options to edit the -Xmx property of the container to increase the memory size